# Reading text from SysTreeView32 in another process

Tags: c#, winapi, treeview, sendmessage

I finally managed to make this work but there's a lot here I don't yet understand.

1. I found information for wparam and lparam on learn.microsoft.com but could not find the actual hexadecimal values associated with them other than an example on this website.  Where is that information?
2. Is there a better way of doing this?  I've seen mention of AutoIt and UI Automation but I don't know much about them yet.

   ```
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Text;

    namespace ConsoleApp8
    {
        public class Program
        {
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
            static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, uint nSize, out UIntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, uint nSize, out UIntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            public static extern bool VirtualFreeEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, uint dwFreeType);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hWndParent, IntPtr hWndChildAfter, string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

            private const int TV_FIRST = 0x1100;
            public enum TVM
            {
                TVM_GETNEXTITEM = (TV_FIRST + 10),
                TVM_GETITEMA = (TV_FIRST + 12),
                TVM_GETITEM = (TV_FIRST + 62),
                TVM_GETCOUNT = (TV_FIRST + 5),
                TVM_SELECTITEM = (TV_FIRST + 11),
                TVM_DELETEITEM = (TV_FIRST + 1),
                TVM_EXPAND = (TV_FIRST + 2),
                TVM_GETITEMRECT = (TV_FIRST + 4),
                TVM_GETINDENT = (TV_FIRST + 6),
                TVM_SETINDENT = (TV_FIRST + 7),
                TVM_GETIMAGELIST = (TV_FIRST + 8),
                TVM_SETIMAGELIST = (TV_FIRST + 9),
                TVM_GETISEARCHSTRING = (TV_FIRST + 64),
                TVM_HITTEST = (TV_FIRST + 17),
            }

            public enum TVGN
            {
                TVGN_ROOT = 0x0,
                TVGN_NEXT = 0x1,
                TVGN_PREVIOUS = 0x2,
                TVGN_PARENT = 0x3,
                TVGN_CHILD = 0x4,
                TVGN_FIRSTVISIBLE = 0x5,
                TVGN_NEXTVISIBLE = 0x6,
                TVGN_PREVIOUSVISIBLE = 0x7,
                TVGN_DROPHILITE = 0x8,
                TVGN_CARET = 0x9,
                TVGN_LASTVISIBLE = 0xA
            }

            [Flags]
            public enum TVIF
            {
                TVIF_TEXT = 1,
                TVIF_IMAGE = 2,
                TVIF_PARAM = 4,
                TVIF_STATE = 8,
                TVIF_HANDLE = 16,
                TVIF_SELECTEDIMAGE = 32,
                TVIF_CHILDREN = 64,
                TVIF_INTEGRAL = 0x0080,
                TVIF_DI_SETITEM = 0x1000
            }

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct TVITEMEX
            {
                public uint mask;
                public IntPtr hItem;
                public uint state;
                public uint stateMask;
                public IntPtr pszText;
                public int cchTextMax;
                public int iImage;
                public int iSelectedImage;
                public int cChildren;
                public IntPtr lParam;
                public int iIntegral;
                public uint uStateEx;
                public IntPtr hwnd;
                public int iExpandedImage;
                public int iReserved;
            }

            // privileges
            const int PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD = 0x0002;
            const int PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400;
            const int PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = 0x0008;
            const int PROCESS_VM_WRITE = 0x0020;
            const int PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010;

            // used for memory allocation
            const uint MEM_COMMIT = 0x00001000;
            const int MEM_DECOMMIT = 0x4000;
            const uint MEM_RESERVE = 0x00002000;
            const uint PAGE_READWRITE = 4;

            public static void Main()
            {
                Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName("GD2");
                IntPtr hMain = p[0].MainWindowHandle;

                IntPtr hWnd1 = FindWindowEx(hMain, IntPtr.Zero, "XTPDockingPaneTabbedContainer", null);
                IntPtr hWnd2 = FindWindowEx(hWnd1, IntPtr.Zero, "XTPShortcutBar", null);
                IntPtr hWnd3 = FindWindowEx(hWnd2, IntPtr.Zero, "Afx:00400000:0:00010007:00000000:00000000", null);
                IntPtr hWnd4 = FindWindowEx(hWnd3, IntPtr.Zero, "SysTreeView32", null);

                IntPtr test1 = SendMessage(hWnd4, (int)TVM.TVM_GETNEXTITEM, (int)TVGN.TVGN_CARET, 0);
                //IntPtr test2 = SendMessage(hWnd4, (int)TVM.TVM_GETCOUNT, 0, 0);

                NodeData testNode = AllocTest(p[0], hWnd4, test1);
            }

            ///<summary>Returns the tree node information from another process.</summary>
            ///<param name="hwndItem">Handle to a tree node item.</param>
            ///<param name="hwndTreeView">Handle to a tree view control.</param>
            ///<param name="process">Process hosting the tree view control.</param>
            private static NodeData AllocTest(Process process, IntPtr hwndTreeView, IntPtr hwndItem)
            {
                // code based on article posted here: http://www.codingvision.net/miscellaneous/c-inject-a-dll-into-a-process-w-createremotethread

                // handle of the process with the required privileges
                IntPtr procHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ, false, process.Id);

                // Write TVITEM to memory
                // Invoke TVM_GETITEM
                // Read TVITEM from memory

                var item = new TVITEMEX();
                item.hItem = hwndItem;
                item.mask = (int)(TVIF.TVIF_HANDLE | TVIF.TVIF_CHILDREN | TVIF.TVIF_TEXT);
                item.cchTextMax = 1024;
                item.pszText = VirtualAllocEx(procHandle, IntPtr.Zero, (uint)item.cchTextMax, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE); // node text pointer

                byte[] data = getBytes(item);

                uint dwSize = (uint)data.Length;
                IntPtr allocMemAddress = VirtualAllocEx(procHandle, IntPtr.Zero, dwSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE); // TVITEM pointer

                uint nSize = dwSize;
                UIntPtr bytesWritten;
                bool successWrite = WriteProcessMemory(procHandle, allocMemAddress, data, nSize, out bytesWritten);

                var sm = SendMessage(hwndTreeView, (int)TVM.TVM_GETITEM, IntPtr.Zero, allocMemAddress);

                UIntPtr bytesRead;
                bool successRead = ReadProcessMemory(procHandle, allocMemAddress, data, nSize, out bytesRead);

                UIntPtr bytesReadText;
                byte[] nodeText = new byte[item.cchTextMax];
                bool successReadText = ReadProcessMemory(procHandle, item.pszText, nodeText, (uint)item.cchTextMax, out bytesReadText);

                bool success1 = VirtualFreeEx(procHandle, allocMemAddress, dwSize, MEM_DECOMMIT);
                bool success2 = VirtualFreeEx(procHandle, item.pszText, (uint)item.cchTextMax, MEM_DECOMMIT);

                var item2 = fromBytes<TVITEMEX>(data);

                String name = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(nodeText);
                int x = name.IndexOf('\0');
                if (x >= 0)
                    name = name.Substring(0, x);

                NodeData node = new NodeData();
                node.Text = name;
                node.HasChildren = (item2.cChildren == 1);

                return node;
            }

            public class NodeData
            {
                public String Text { get; set; }
                public bool HasChildren { get; set; }
            }

            private static byte[] getBytes(Object item)
            {
                int size = Marshal.SizeOf(item);
                byte[] arr = new byte[size];
                IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

                Marshal.StructureToPtr(item, ptr, true);
                Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, size);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

                return arr;
            }

            private static T fromBytes<T>(byte[] arr)
            {
                T item = default(T);
                int size = Marshal.SizeOf(item);
                IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
                Marshal.Copy(arr, 0, ptr, size);
                item = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(T));
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
                return item;
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: The constants are defined in the Win32 SDK header files for C/C++. Microsoft's documentation frequently omits the actual values, only mentioning the symbolic names. For C#, refer to sites like http://pinvoke.net for definitions.

Comment: In any case, why are you asking for `PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD` and `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` permissions from `OpenProcess()`? You are not creating a remote thread, or querying process metadata. This code only needs the 3 `VM` permissions, don't ask for more permissions than you actually need.

Comment: On a side note - you should check if the TreeView's `HWND` is a Unicode window or an ANSI window (see [`IsWindowUnicode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-iswindowunicode)). If it is Unicode (as your use of `Encoding.Unicode` implies), you would have to allocate `cchTextMax * 2` bytes for your text buffers. `cchTextMax` is expressed in *characters*, not in *bytes*. Windows uses UTF-16 for Unicode text, and UTF-16 `char`s are 2 bytes each. So, for Unicode, `cchTextMax` needs to be *1/2* of the allocated buffer size.

Comment: Use UI Automation

Comment: What message are you talking about? It's recommended to use UI Automation instead of breaking down processes.